# Prefactors for Fourier Transforms in Altland Simons

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator

I am trying to understand how to do the Fourier Transform on pages 184 - 185 in Altland Simons(2nd ed). In particular, we are told in the problem statement part b:

$$ S[\theta] = \frac{1}{2 c} \int dx d \tau [(\partial_\tau \theta)^2 + (\partial_x  \theta)^2] $$

Writing in terms of a Fourier series:

$$ \partial_\tau \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta L}} \sum_{\omega_{\, n} \, , \, p} \theta_{n, p} \; e^{i (px - \omega_{\, n} \; \tau)} \; \; (-i \omega_n) \; $$
$$ \partial_x \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\beta L}} \sum_{\omega_{\, n} \, , \, p} \theta_{n, p} \; e^{i (px - \omega_{\, n} \; \tau)} \; \; (ip) \; $$

Now using the formulas:

$$ \int_0^\beta d \tau e^{- i \omega_{\, n} \; \tau} = \beta \delta_{\omega_{\, n} \, , \, 0} \; $$
$$ \frac{1}{L} \int dx e^{-i (k + k') x} = \delta_{k + k', 0}\; $$
$$ \beta \equiv \frac{1}{T} \; $$

the first from page 168 (right below eq. 4.32), the second from the first line of page 21, and the third from page 166 (right below eq. 4.23), we find:

$$ S[\theta] = \frac{1}{2c} \sum_{p, n} |\theta_{p, n} \, |^2 \, (p^2 + \omega_n^2 \, ) $$

since the prefactor $\frac{1}{\beta L}$ arising from $(\partial_\tau \theta)^2, (\partial_x \theta)^2$ is canceled by the $\beta, L$ from the first two formulas under "now using the formulas".

However, on page 185 in the solution section AS gives the answer as

$$ S[\theta] = \frac{L}{2cT} \sum_{p, n} |\theta_{p, n} \, |^2 \, (p^2 + \omega_n^2 \, ), $$

which has an additional factor of $\frac{L}{T}$.

Comment: Could you add the edition of the book and the numbers of equations?

Comment: Sure, will do that now.

Comment: A list of errors for the first edition (I think) can be found [here](http://www.thp.uni-koeln.de/alexal/images/book_errors.pdf). You could check whether your concerns are listed there. Of course, even if not listed there, it could be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply that they use a weird normalization of their Fourier modes. To get the same action that they use, define $\theta_{p,n}$ via
$$
\theta_{p,n} = \frac{1}{\beta L} \int_0^{\beta}\! d\tau \int_0^L \! dx \ e^{i (\omega_n \tau - kx)}  \theta(\tau,x), \quad \theta(\tau,x) = \sum_{k,n} e^{-i(\omega_n \tau - kx)} \theta_{p,n}
$$
This is essentially changing the normalization of $\theta_{p,n}$ by a factor $\sqrt{\beta L}$. This normalization is a little bit silly (if anything, I would put the factor of $\beta L$ on the Fourier sum instead of the integral for ease of taking $L,\beta \rightarrow \infty$), but there's no reason you can't do it. Note that the result of the Gaussian integral is independent of your choice of Fourier decomposition, as it must be: if the factor of $T/L$ didnt come from the prefactor in the action, it would instead come from expanding $\theta(x,t)$ in Fourier modes inside the correlation function.